# Solenoid valve triggering

Tags: mosfet, arduino-uno, solenoid-valve

Will a solenoid valve if kept in on condition (triggered) all day long cause it to burn itself, due to the heat it produces or for any other reason?
Rating - (24V DC, 2A, normally closed, 1 inch, pressure limit 10 bar).

Comment: What does the manufacturer’s datasheet say? That’s the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Generally you should drive a solenoid with a relay economizer, both to avoid the problem of possible damage to the solenoid, and to reduce the power consumed when all you're doing is keeping it held in place. Some solenoids are designed to be run at full current continuously, though; check the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

If it overheats it will burn out,  arrange sufficient cooling that it does not overheat.

At about 48W it will produce quite a lot of heat,  depending on what's in its neighbourhood and ambient temperature
thermal convection may be enough to cool it or may not.